# Installing a package

Tags: package-management, android, crunchbang

I am running crunchbang linux and I would like to know if there is a way to install the Android Developent Tools as a package on my computer. I already have it extracted to a folder in my ~/downloads directory, how do i "install it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can install this using your system's package manager, if that's what you're asking.

You might want to install Eclipse as a package, and then install ADT as an Eclipse plugin. This is detailed here on the Android.com website in this articled titled: [Installing the Eclipse Plugin](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html).

Often times with Eclipse installed you can configure it to make use of its own repositories for downloading plugins, so you could probably install ADT through this mechanism which would allow you to keep it isolated as a installation.